# Regex which allows only letters without accents

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex or function or method to make my own function to allow only letters without accents.

1. Leo     : Allowed!
2. Leo5    : Not allowed
3. Léo     : Not allowed

Comment: You have not demonstrated any effort to do any research before asking, if you had you would notice this question has been asked over and over again. Therefore, could you show what research if any you carried out before asking this question?

Comment: Yes because I'm persuaded "/^[A-Za-z]+$/m" allows accents.. Sorry

Comment: Did you try testing it first?

Comment: I said "I'm persuaded" so no, but you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI0aX0/1)**

You could use:

```
$re = "/^[A-Za-z]+$/m"; 
// $re = "/^[a-z]+$/im"; // You can use this option too

$str = "Leo\nLeo5\nLéo"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I persuaded with that it will allow accents.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need regex:

```
if(ctype_alpha('Léo')) {
    //allowed
} else {
    //not allowed
}
```

Comment: I like this more than my regex answer :) +1

Comment: But your regex don't allows number ;)

Comment: If you want numbers even though the question shows that you don't then `ctype_alnum()`

Comment: Because I wanted only username without number or accents. Do you think is better to use ctype_alnum() + ctype_alpha() rather than Fede's regex ?

Comment: What?  You're flip flopping.  `ctype_alpha()` is only letters no accents no numbers.